# Autocomplete TextField move down other views in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I wrote an AutoCompletet TextField in Jetpack Compose. I used this view in a Row and between two others' views. The side views move down when autocomplete dropdown is opened. How can I fix this issue?

The Link of GIF file is end of page. in the GIF you can see side views of Autocomplete move to bottom when the suggest items is shows.

**My AutoComplete codes:**

```
@Composable
    fun AutoCompleteTextField(
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
        list: List<Product>,
        searchTerm: TextFieldValue,
        updateSearchTerm: (TextFieldValue) -> Unit,
    ) {

        var product by remember {
            mutableStateOf("")
        }

        var heightTextFields by remember {
            mutableStateOf(55.dp)
        }

        var textFieldSize by remember {
            mutableStateOf(Size.Zero)
        }

        var expanded by remember {
            mutableStateOf(false)
        }

        val interactionSource = remember {
            MutableInteractionSource()
        }

        Column(
            modifier = modifier
                .width(200.dp)
//            .padding(30.dp)
                .clickable(
                    interactionSource = interactionSource,
                    indication = null,
                    onClick = {
                        expanded = false
                    }
                )
        ) {

            Column(modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                Row(
                    modifier = modifier
                        .border(BorderStroke(width = 1.dp, color = Color.LightGray))
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {

                    IconButton(onClick = {product = "" }) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Filled.Add,
                            contentDescription = "Add",
                            modifier = modifier
                                .padding(4.dp)
                                .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
                        )
                    }
                    TextField(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .height(heightTextFields)
                            .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                                textFieldSize = coordinates.size.toSize()
                            },
                        value = product,
                        onValueChange = {
                            product = it
                            expanded = true
                        },
                        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                            backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                            focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                            unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                            cursorColor = Color.Black
                        ),
                        textStyle = TextStyle(
                            fontFamily = shabnamFontFamily,
                            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary,
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                            fontSize = 14.sp,
                        ),
                        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
                            imeAction = ImeAction.Done
                        ),
                        singleLine = true,
                    )
                }

                AnimatedVisibility(visible = expanded) {
                    Card(
                        modifier = modifier
                            .padding(horizontal = 4.dp)
                            .width(textFieldSize.width.dp),
                        elevation = 10.dp,
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(bottomStart = 4.dp, bottomEnd = 4.dp)
                    ) {

                        LazyColumn(
                            modifier = Modifier.heightIn(max = 150.dp),
                        ) {

                            if (product.isNotEmpty()) {
                                items(
                                    list.filter {
                                        it.productName.lowercase()
                                            .contains(product.lowercase())
                                    }
                                ) { item ->
                                    ProductItems(title = item.productName) { title ->
                                        product = title
                                        expanded = false
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                items(
                                    items =
                                    list
                                ) { item ->
                                    ProductItems(title = item.productName) { title ->
                                        product = title
                                        expanded = false
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }

                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

[Screen GIF file](https://easyupload.io/zk0mq0)

Comment: You want to align this element in z index, not in x-axis.
Replace root element `Column` with `Box`, and set `Modifier.offset(y = 50.dp)` to the custom drop down `Card` as the height of your `TextField` let say 50.dp.

Comment: @HimanshuBansal It's not working

Comment: I want to open the menu below of textFled exactly.

Comment: Ignore above solution, try this
Wrap your `AnimatedVisibility` Composable in Popup Composable,
```
 Popup(
                onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }
            ) {
               AnimatedVisibility(visible = expanded) {
  ...
              }
}
```

Comment: You can alternatively use `DropdownMenu`, see if you can modify it with your use case.

Comment: Yes, It's worked but I added the offset modifier too. Thank you                                         Popup( onDismissRequest = { expanded = false, offset = IntOffset(x = -6, y = 150) }